# Create multiple OneDrive drives

Tags: onedrive

The new(ish) OneDrive API [docs](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm#root-resources) talk about multiple drives:

> /drives   List Drives available to the authenticated user.

However I only have a single (default) drive for my account. I can't find any info about how to create additional drives, or whether this is even possible at the moment. Maybe you get the option somewhere if you buy extra storage or use OneDrive for Business? Having said that [this](https://dev.onedrive.com/odb-preview/release-notes.htm) says:

> The /drives/{drive-id} syntax is not supported for OneDrive for Business. You should always use the default drive syntax: /drive/.

Is it possible to create additional drives (manually or via the API) and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to create additional drives.

Comment: So is there any use for the `/drives/{drive-id}` path currently? Is there any scenario where a user can end up with multiple drives? If not I assume this is a possible feature for the future?

Comment: For the most part it's a future proofing decision - there are scenarios we can foresee where such a capability would be desirable.