# Can a user have multiple "drives"?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I would like to get some clarification about OneDrive and `Drives` of a user.

There are many examples in Microsoft Graph where a request to get user's drive occurred with help of "**drives**":

```
/users/{userEmail}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children
```

In [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_list) it states that "Most users will only have a single Drive resource".

What are there cases where a user could have multiple `drives`?

I found a related question where it said this is not possible now but the last answer is from 2015 and it links to older release notes: 
[Create multiple OneDrive drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503439/create-multiple-onedrive-drives).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `user` resource, there is only a single `drive`. It is possible that at some point this would change but I'm aware of any mechanism for generating additional drives today.

The reason for the `/drives/{drive-id}` pattern however is because this API covers more resources than just a `user`. For other resource types, multiple drives is quite common. A SharePoint `site` for example may have any number of "Document Libraries", each of which would surface within the OneDrive API as a distinct `drive`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! You really made my day!